# Как задать проверку на наличие класса в теге?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем добрый день! Задача такая: есть тег `<input>`, нужно, чтобы скрипт проверял наличие в нем класса .val, и если класс есть, то выполнял дальнейшие инструкции, при этом этот класс динамически удаляется и вставляется, т.е. если он был, а потом его удалили и снова вставили, то скрипт опять должен срабатывать.

Comment: @Dragomaster, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('input').hasClass('className')) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @andreyqin опередил. :(

Comment: hasClass проверяет один раз, а нужно, чтобы проверка была постоянной.

Comment: Распишите задачу более подробно. Я понимаю, что вам нужно, но скорее всего вашу задачу можно решить иначе.

Comment: Есть тег input, в него другой js-скрипт динамически вставляет и удаляет класс .val, так вот, как отловить это изменение тега, не меняя при этом тот скрипт?

Comment: Про live() почитайте.

Comment: live() удален начиная с 1.7 версии.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то можно переопределить функции добавления и удаления класса перед этим скриптом и перед вызовом оригинального метода производить необходимые действия. Подробнее - http://hashcode.ru/questions/19240/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Если мне не изменяет память, то функция `hasClass()` проверяет наличие класса в jQuery

```
$("input").hasClass("val")
```

либо

```
$("input").is("val")
```

или

```
$("input").has("val")
```

вроде бы это будет выглядеть как то так, если что поправьте.

Answer (score 0):

Постарался максимально расписать(если я правильно понял условие):

```js
$('#check').click(function(){
  var val = $('#input').val();//создаём переменную со значением введённым в input
  if($('#input').hasClass(val)){//если есть класс val
    alert('Класс есть');
    $('#input').removeClass(val);//удалить класс val у этого элемента
    alert('Класс удалён');
  }else{//иначе, если нет класса val
    alert('Класса нет');
    $('#input').addClass(val);//добавить класс val
    alert('Класс добавлен');
    
  }
});
```

```css
.active{
background:red;
}
input{
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" class="red">
<button id="check">Проверить класс</button>
```